# Update TJSONArray

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

How to correctly update json value?
Here is what I tried, but without luck:

```
TJSONArray *Data;
Data = (TJSONArray*) TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(TEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes(json),0);
TJSONObject *obj = (TJSONObject*) Data->Get(0);
TJSONArray *arr = (TJSONArray*) obj->Get("tokens");
arr = (TJSONArray*) TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(TEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes(arrjson),0);
```

Data:

```
[{"source":"aaaa","cluster":"1","tokens":[{},{}]}, {"source":"bbbb","cluster":"2","tokens":[{},{}]}]
```

Comment: Your code does not match your json, and you did not show any attempt to actually update the contents of the array. What exactly are you trying to accomplish, and what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Have you looked at `TJSONArray`'s methods instead, like `Add()` and `AddElement()`? Or its `Items[]` property?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I want to update the tokens array, I did not tried Add or AddElement because it's method name suggests to Add,  but I want  to update with new tokens array, I need to Set a value, overwrite existing value

Comment: that is actually quite difficult to do with an array of objects (it would be easier with an array of strings, for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `TJSONArray` does not *natively* allow you to REPLACE existing elements with new values (Why? Who knows).  All you can do is ADD and REMOVE elements, and ENUMERATE elements.

Since your array holds `TJSONObject` instances, to replace such an element with a new object, you will have to either:

1. remove all of the elements from the array including and following the desired element index, then add a new object of the desired type, and then re-add the removed elements (in their previous order).
2. construct a completely new `TJSONArray`, and then add objects to it as needed, copying values from the previous `TJSONArray` where needed.  You can then get the `TJSONPair` for the `tokens` field and set the new `TJSONArray` as its `JsonValue`.

If this is not to your liking, then look for a 3rd party JSON library that supports the editing capabilities you are interested in.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, because I spent time playing this without finding a proper way to achive this. So I trust your experience and will accept your answer next days if no other answer will offer a better solution. But do you know if it is better if I replace entirely object like: {"source":"aaaa","cluster":"1","tokens":[{},{}]}

Comment: Or maybe remove the object from root array, and then add updated one which have the tokens array updated.  I'm not sure if this is doable using native way